# Unable to make Skype videocall in Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: skype, webcam

I have Lenovo Ideapad-Z560 laptop with Ubuntu 14.04 (64-bit), iBall external cam USB 2.0.

Skype 4.3

I am unable to make video call in Skype. When I go to *Skype*-->*Options*-->*Video Devices*, it recognize the webcam. In skype it does not show the option to do videocall. I never faced such problems with Skype in Windows OS.

Please someone suggest me a solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just start a normal call and then click on the video button on the skype call. (See image). It's the leftmost round blue icon. Skype for Linux isn't up to date as the other OS' so you'll need some time to get used to it I guess. Also I want to add that skype video conferences DON'T work on linux yet.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.But while I was searching for the solution, I got the below link as an answer to this.
Video option will be enabled once call is connected.

https://support.skype.com/en/faq/FA10958/how-do-i-make-a-video-call-in-skype-for-linux

In the link, Step 5 is mentioned as below,

When the call is answered, click  in the call window and select Start my Video.
You will immediately start to transmit your video to the other caller, providing your webcam is configured correctly.

Comment: Please include the appropriate parts of the link you included in your answer. Thanks